# Transact SQL Query Help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm really not good with SQL and i just want to write a query that shows some log data in a chart.

I have a SQL Server table where i log requests made to a web service.

```
ID          RequestedFunction       RequestDateTime
1           'Confirm()'             2010-12-15 13:27:01.234
2           'Register()'            2010-12-16 12:27:00.678
3           'Confirm()'             2010-12-16 21:00:05.456
```

Now i'd like write a query that return me the number of requests made per day grouped by RequestedFunction; that return me a dataset like this.

```
Day          ConfirmFunctionRequests       RegisterFunctionRequests
15           1                             0
16           1                             1
```

Is this possible? All i could come up with so far is something like this,

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT id, 
    [Day] = CAST(day(requestDateTime) AS INT),
    RequestedFunction
FROM [Log]
WHERE month(RequestDateTime)=12 AND
year(RequestDateTime)=2010
)
SELECT [Day],COUNT(ID) AS [#Requests] FROM CTE GROUP BY [Day]
```

Which returns the number of requests per day, without differentiating between different types of requests. How can i write a query that counts the requests in to two different columns based on the value in 'RequestedFunction'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) but a quick and simple solution would be something like

```
DECLARE @Log TABLE(
        ID INT,
        RequestedFunction VARCHAR(50),
        RequestDateTime DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Log SELECT 1,'Confirm()','2010-12-15 13:27:01.234' 
INSERT INTO @Log SELECT 2,'Register()','2010-12-16 12:27:00.678'
INSERT INTO @Log SELECT 3,'Confirm()','2010-12-16 21:00:05.456'

SELECT  DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,RequestDateTime)) DayValue,
        SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN RequestedFunction = 'Confirm()' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END 
            ) ConfirmFunctionRequests,
        SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN RequestedFunction = 'Register()' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )RegisterFunctionRequests
FROM    @Log
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,RequestDateTime))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering, can i also use DATEPART(dd,RequestDateTime) as an alternative to DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,RequestDateTime))?

Comment: The only problem with that is that it will then only group by day, so if you have entries that are on the 15 Jan and 15 Feb, it will add them together

Comment: Yes I wanted to restrict that using a WHERE clause and also do hours per given day, etc. I tried using DATEADD(hh,0, DATEDIFF(hh,0,RequestDateTime)) for hours but the output didn't seem very readable.